# Emberjs equivalent to handle_change event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, socket.io

Is there EmberJS equivalent `handle_change` event from Backbone?

I'm trying to implement pub/sub with socket.io, node.js, redis and Ember.js with Rails but aren't sure how it would be received by EmberJS.

Could this be from Route file?

This is the code I've got:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend ->
    setupController: (controller, data) ->
        socket = io.connect()
        self = this
        socket.on 'ticket/new', (ticket) ->
            store.load App.Ticket, ticket
```

Comment: I would be useful to see where and when you want to handle the change event, some code extract from your implemenation is much appreciated

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated with codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach of setting up the socked in the controller looks good.  (You might want to make sure to hold on to the socket in a controller variable.)

For the latest Ember Data you'd want to use `store.push`

```
this.store.push('ticket',ticket);
```

Here's a JSBin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1081/edit